# How can I find elements that are geometrical close together?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of locations, some of them are duplicated in a way, that they are close together (like 1 or 2 meters away from each other).

Is there a way to find elements where the locations are close to each other?

I tried something with aggregation like:

```js
db.places.aggregate([
   {
     $geoNear: {
        near: "$location",
        distanceField: "distance",
     }
   }
])
```

I know that that can't work, but to give you a better understanding on what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use $lookup with the same collection for that.

Within the lookup pipeline:

- use $geoNear to find all documents in the places collection
- $match to eliminate the self reference from the result
  Then $match to return only places that have another place very close.

I tested the below with MongoDB 7.0:

```
db.places.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "places",
      let: {
         loc: "$location",
         id: "$_id"
      },
      as: "close",
      pipeline: [
          { $geoNear: {
                near: "$$loc",
                distanceField: "distance",
                maxDistance: 10
          }},
          {$match: { $expr: {$ne: ["$_id", "$$id"] }}}
      ]
   }},
   {$match: {
      "close.0": {$exists: true},
   }}
])
```